# Hiding the legend in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using the Google charts API. Is there a way to hide the legend for a scatter plot?

Answer (score 403, accepted):

You can disable the legend by using 'none' as the position:

`legend: {position: 'none'}`

Comment: This actually works. Haven't tried the other suggestion. Remember should go in the options: `var options = {legend:{position:'none'}};`

Comment: This removes the title too!

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, remove all legends etc, work on visualization version 1 "google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["bar"] });"

Comment: Google's documentation on charts is so bad.

Answer (score 97):

A bit cleaner way is

```
legend: 'none'
```

Comment: Still working for me today (17/009/2015). I'm using "google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['controls', "corechart", "calendar"]});"

Comment: This didn't work for me on 07.10.2016 (dd.mm.yyyy), although the original accepted answer worked.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on September 23, 2017. The accepted answer works.

Answer (score 12):

```
var options = {
               title: 'USA City Distribution',
               legend: 'none'
              };
```

In `drawChart()` function, Add `legend: none` property in your chart options object

Answer (score 3):

In my case I use:

library: {legend:{position:'none'}}

> pie_chart @type_values,**library: {legend:{position:'none'}}**

Answer (score -7):

It doesn't appear so from the API, you can only set a position, with no option for "none". You could probably remove it with javascript though, if you can identify the containing element.

Edit: it actually appears as though you can omit the chdl= parameter to get a scatter without a legend.