# How do I remove the legend from a Google geoChart?

Tags: google-visualization

How do I remove the legend that appears in the bottom of the Google geoChart? I know that if I don't pass data.setValue to the chart object it wont show, but I need them to populate the map. All I want to do is get rid of the colors. Any ideas?

Comment: "How do I remove the legend" yes the legend that shows in the bottom left of the google svg world map chart

Answer (score 35, accepted):

See : http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html#Configuration_Options

> "An object with members to configure various aspects of the legend, **or 'none', if no legend should appear.**"

So basically, when you're passing your configuration options into the API, you want to include the following:

`legend: 'none'`

A simple example set of chart options would be:

```
var options = {
    displayMode: 'markers',
    colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']},
    legend: 'none',
}
```

The modified version of the marker example provided by google on: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html#Examples

Comment: Hey IntreipdBrit, thanks for the comment. Do you know if this was just added or has it always been there?

Comment: I have no idea, only recently started using Google Charts.

Comment: It doesn't work for me...this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202029/hiding-the-legend-in-google-chart works instead

Answer (score 2):

Set the option legend to none.

```
legend: 'none'
```

This hides the legend/colorAxis displayed at the left bottom corner of the chart.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently there isn't a way to do this. If you are using google geoMap wich renders a Flash object then there is a simple property you set to false in the geoMap object to not render the legend on the bottom left. I did how ever using jQuery manage to remove it but that just doesn't flow nicely given that it has to exist in the DOM before you can remove it. If you are seeking to use a world map I strongly recommend [jVecotor Map](http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/).
It renders exactly the same in old IE browsers and has less vectors in the map so it is faster to load since the DOM is not over saturated.