# Hide specific legend in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have written code for Area Chart which has the functionality to hide the corresponding area if I click on a particular label, similar to [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20459237/586051).

The problem is if I click on a particular legend, the corresponding area and ALL legends are getting hidden. This is happening because I am doing,

```
var options = {legend: 'none'};
```

Is there a way that I can hide only the clicked legend (along with the corresponding area)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is trying to hide the whole legend, not an area in the chart based on a click in a legend.

Trying looking at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6gz2Q - you basically need to create your chart in a specific way and add an on select listener to catch the event when the legend is clicked:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(){
   ...
});
```

Please note, the code in the example link is not mine, but it helped me with the same exact problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that my code helped you!  @Rahul Desai, if this example works for you, I'd be happy to answer any questions you have about implementing it.

Comment: @asgallant Your code looks great! One modification I need in this is that only the first legend should not respond to the click, I need to keep it instead of showing the chart empty, for that I added `return false;` in my code, but it didnt help. I am getting an error `selection[0] is undefined`, where `selection` is `chart.getSelection();`. Same trick works very well in your fiddle though.

Comment: @asgallant I solved that problem! I realized that the graph has to be plotted in any case, so I did. :)

Comment: @asgallant Would it be possible to add a close button next to the legend so that onClick, the corresponding area is hidden and also the legend is taken off?

Comment: Do you want to turn the legend off, or remove the series from the legend?  If you remove the series from the legend or turn off the legend entirely, there won't be a way to add a series back to the chart later (unless you code in some other means).