# google charts remove text on bottom

Tags: javascript, graph, charts

i am using google charts for displaying some user stats.
How can I remove text on bottom of google line chart?

Check in red circle

http://i49.tinypic.com/se3cpj.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Hiding the legend in Google Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202029/hiding-the-legend-in-google-chart)

Comment: This only remove legend on right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
hAxis: { textPosition: 'none' }
```

View the related documentation here (search for "textPosition"): https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

So a full, simple example would be this:

```
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

    data.addRows([
        [0, 0], [1, 10], [2, 23], [3, 17], [4, 18], [5, 9],
        [6, 11], [7, 27], [8, 33], [9, 40], [10, 32], [11, 35],
        [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
        [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
        [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
        [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
        [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
        [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
        [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
        [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
        [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
        [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
    ]);

    var options = {
        hAxis: {
            textPosition: 'none'
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Popularity'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Run the code yourself here: [​https://jsfiddle.net/p80uggL0/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/p80uggL0/3/)

Comment: What's with the unexplained down vote? Is it no longer working?

Comment: It's working; the only thing I could think of, other than a grumpy person spreading their grumps, is that the link to the visualization playground was no longer functional. Updated to a jsfiddle, and updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing x-axis label font color same as background color like this

```
chart.draw(daily, {
    hAxis : {textColor: '#ffffff'},
    [... your other options here ...]
});
```

if its not working use `hAxis: {baselineColor: '#FFFFFF'}` instead of `textColor`, anyone of these should work.

Comment: Is working! Now is dont show but is still here. Does have any option to remove this?

Comment: Try none instead of #ffffff;  like baselineColor: 'none' . Also try this hAxis: {baselineColor: 'none', gridlines: {color: 'none'}}

Answer (score 0):

if it is PieChart, and then like this.

legend : { position : 'none' }

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
        fontSize: 10,
         legend : { position : 'none' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```